# Generating an automatically incrementing integer in flask-sqlalchemy which is not a primary_key

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I am creating a database in flask-sqlalchemy. I'd like one of the rows to have an automatically generated integer in increments of one, which I can change dynamically externally. I would like this to not be a primary_key, as the integer will be changed regularly. This number will be used for a queue system. Are there any practical methods I can use for this issue?

Comment: What's the database ?

Answer (score 0):

U can use a global variable to store and update the integer value (or) u can also store the integer in a text file and read and update the integer value from the text file.